# Is there a way to hide addressbar in webchromeclient?

Tags: android, android-layout, webchromeclient

I am developing an android application in which I want to show a website, which have links in it. When any link is clicked, then it plays an online stream.

Till now I have developed an app which work alright. In this I have used webview to display first screen. The live stream is not supported in **webview**, so I used **webchromeclient**.

Now the problem is when any link is clicked, a new browser opens and plays the stream and also shows the address bar and address of page loaded page.

I want to hide the address of new loaded page. 
and if possible, also I wnt to keep  **webchromeclient** in existing screen, not a new browser.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you have to customize the `WebViewClient` like this

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Then create an instance of this new WebViewClient for the WebView:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

for further have a look on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html), and read carefully

Comment: webview does not support .m3u8 based video streaming, but webchromeclient plays it fine. So, it is must for me to open link using webchromeclient. :(